# How can i fill my Panels with GridLayoutmanager

Tags: intellij-idea, gridlayoutmanager

firstly look at https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV03B.jpg

I have a project where I wanna show a Table with some data.
it show the data but the panels dont fill verticaly and horizontaly.
I use the GridLayoutManager from com.intellij.uiDesigner.core

[thats how it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYvxE.png)

The table has its own panel and class where it gets its data
the class below the table is just a baseClass with all buttons (so i dont need to rewrite the class all the time) and a panel for the table, where it should be filled, and the mainView where i wanna add the tableView and fill it in the panel  where it should be added. View first Image

Edit:
i add all panels with `mainPanel.add(panelToAdd,new GridConstraints());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works.
You need to add GridConstraints and set the LayoutManager to these JPanels

```
GridConstraints constraints = new GridConstraints();
constraints.setFill(GridConstraints.FILL_BOTH);
this.setLayout(new GridLayoutManager(1,1));

this.add(mainPanel, constraints);
```